# Use Central Limit Theorem to estimate the probability of Heads in coin toss

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $S_{100}$ be the number of heads that turn in in 100 tosses of a fair coin. Use Central limit theorem to estimate:

Here is a z-score table: http://gyazo.com/b98bdd329d4c1ac5ade0630073f88c6f

a) P($S_{100} \leq 45$)

b) P($45 \leq S_{100} \leq 55$)

c) P($S_{100} \geq 63$)

---

When I attempt this question, I get a z-score of 99.1 for the first one and It seems that I don't have the right approach here. I'm using the formula $$P(S_n \leq b) = P\left(Z \leq \frac {b-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right) $$

For the values, I use:

b = 45, n = 100, $\mu$ = 50 ($\mu$ = $np$ because binomial distribution), $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p}$ = 5

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. My z-score becomes 99.1 using these values and that doesn't seem right.

Comment: If μ = np the expectation of S_n is μ, not nμ. If the expectation of S_n is nμ, then μ = p, not np.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $S_{100}$ as a sum of $100$ independent indicator variables, $X_1$ through $X_{100}$, each denoting whether a head occurred in the $i$-th toss. Now, $\mathrm{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1}{4}$.

We can use the central limit theorem as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{P}(0 \leq S_{100} \leq 45) & = \mathrm{P}\left(0 \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{100}X_i \leq 45\right) \\& = \mathrm{P}\left( \frac{0 - 100 \cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.25 \cdot100}} \leq \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{100}X_i - 100 \cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.25 \cdot100}} \leq \frac{45 - 100 \cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.25 \cdot100}}\right) \\
& = \mathrm{P}(-10 \leq Z \leq -1) = \Phi(-1) - \Phi(-10) \approx 0.1585
\end{align*}
$$

Where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution.

By the way, this is often called the integral de Moivre–Laplace theorem (or de Moivre–Laplace central limit theorem) when used directly on binomial random variables, as I think it was derived much earlier in time.

Comment: The result would be more exact, if you add the continuity correction factor. At the moment you are almost 3% away from the exact result.